# Why hostname got truncated from the HAProxy syslog messages

Tags: web-server, load-balancing, haproxy

This is a slice from my haproxy logging, where I target the sysloga and remotely log to papertrail, using the `log-send-hostname` option to pront the hostname in the log message instead of the `localhost`:

```
global
  log logs2.papertrailapp.com:12345   local0
  log 127.0.0.1   local1 info
  log-send-hostname
```

Example of log messages:

```
Aug 11 01:43:21 messaging-service-proxy-staging haproxy[10496]: 50.242.120.110:49337 [11/Aug/2015:01:43:21.436] http test-backend/elb 4/0/1/5/10 404 487 - - ---- 0/0/0/0/0 0/0 "GET / HTTP/1.1"

Aug 11 01:43:21 messaging-service-proxy-staging haproxy[10496]: 50.242.120.110:49338 [11/Aug/2015:01:43:21.606] http test-backend/elb 4/0/1/6/11 404 487 - - ---- 0/0/0/0/0 0/0 "GET / HTTP/1.1"
```

So the logged hostname is `messaging-service-proxy-staging` whereas the hostname is `messaging-service-proxy-staging-vpc1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, haproxy seems to only keep 32 characters from hostname value. development-haproxy.limecraft.c has 31 but it also has '\0' at the end. 
I was able to log longer hostname by changing this configuration line, on frontend section in haproxy.cfg:

capture request header Host len 50